# Coding Hangman in Python

Tags: python

I'm having trouble with this hangman coding.  When I run the code, it asks the question "Type in a letter a - z", but when I type in a letter, instead of it putting a letter, it just ask the same question from the beginning without letting me know if the letter is correct or not.

```
import random

possibleAnswers = ["page","computer","cookie","phishing","motherboard","freeware","bus","unix","document","hypertext","node","digital","worm","macro","binary","podcast","paste","virus","toolbar","browser"]

random.shuffle(possibleAnswers)

answers = list(possibleAnswers[1])

display = []
display.extend(answers)

for i in range(len(display)):
    display[i] = "_"

print ' '.join(display)
print "\n\n\n\n"

count = 0

while count < len(answers):

    guess = raw_input("Type in a letter a - z: ")

    guess = guess.upper()

    for i in range(len(answers)):
        if answers[i] == guess:
            display[i] = guess
            count += 1

    print ' '.join(display)
    print "\n\n\n"
```

Comment: `without letting me know if the letter is correct or not` There is no print statement anywhere in your code that explicitly informs the user if their guess was correct, so I'm not sure what you're expecting.

Comment: @JohnGordon: it's the pair of `print`s at the bottom.  `display` is a series of dashes with the correct guesses filled in.

Comment: I figured it was something like that.  My comment was more of a subtle hint to the OP that the problem description wasn't specific enough.  Too subtle, I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

It *does* tell you, after a fashion.  The problem is that your entire word list is lower-case, but you specifically change all of your input guesses to upper-case.  Those cannot match, so there's never a "correct" guess.  Change the word list to capitals, or change your conversion from `upper` to `lower`.